# How to hide multiple command output in fish shell?

Tags: null, output, hide, fish

Let's say there is a set of commands as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env fish

command1
command2
command3
```

Each command prints its own output, which I want to hide. In bash it's rather simple:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
{
command1
command2
command3
} &> /dev/null
```

But it does not work in fish. Is there any solution other than sending each and every command to /dev/null? Can somebody help me with that?

Answer (score 8):

Fish's equivalent to `{}` command grouping is `begin` and `end`, so

```
begin
    command1
    command2
    command3
end &> /dev/null
```

Comment: Thank you. It was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Here is rather crude workaround:

```
#!/usr/bin/env fish

function CommandList
    command1
    command2
    command3
end

CommandList &> /dev/null
```

Hopefully somebody will have a real solution to this problem...